# Magento 2 : get rewrite product url

Tags: magento2, product, url, url-rewrite, magento-2.0

I am trying to get **`rewrite product url`** from the `load product` in custom module. I am getting url in `http://localhost/m2/catalog/product/view/id/1401/category/23/` format .

But I want `http://localhost/m2/juno-jacket.html`

Here is the code

**in constructor**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProductHelper,
) {
    $this->catalogProductHelper = $catalogProductHelper;
}
```

**Custom function**

```
public function abc(){
    $product_id = '123';
    return  $this->catalogProductHelper->getProductUrl($product_id);
}
```

`abc() method` return url like `http://localhost/m2/catalog/product/view/id/1401/category/23/`

Comment: rebuild your indexes

Comment: @Marius : i have rebuild too. It is  not returning product rewrite url.

Comment: is your product associated to any website?

Comment: I have assigned product in main website

Comment: `getProductUrl()` is supposed to return the rewritten URL if the entry exist in `url_rewrite`. Did you delete records from this table manually?

Comment: in which table, it used for rewrite

Comment: @Marius, any idea how to regenerate URL rewrites? It no longer seems to be part of the indexer in M2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the method I used to get the product url.

It is definitely not optimal as I have to load the entire product to get it so very bad in terms of performance.

First you need to inject a `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` in your constructor:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;
//...
public function __construct(
    ProductRepository $productRepository
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

Then you load the product based on the product id:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
```

Finally you can get the URL model to retrieve the rewritten URL:

```
return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
```

Comment: The double comma at the end isn't intended, isn't it?

Comment: @Max yeah totally, I removed it

Comment: I am facing the same and I have tried your code but still the urls are incorrect for me. Please advise.

Comment: Another way (and less perf-killer) may be to force the addition of URL rewrites on product collection load. See my answer.

Comment: same error can you please tell me where i can put this code ?

Comment: This does not return the store url if you have multiple stores enable.

Answer (score 4):

This may not really answer the question but chances are that, if you are missing the URL rewrite, you may be getting your product out of a product collection. And adding URL rewrite info is not automatic as you can see in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::$_addUrlRewrite`.

The way I managed forcing the addition of URL rewrites is by creating a plugin on the `create()` method of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`. And as soon as your code (or Magento's core code) uses this factory for instanciating a product collection (and it should as of best practices), this plugin forces the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::$_addUrlRewrite` to `true`.

Then, products URL rewrites are successfully added to the products without the need to loop on them and reload them. It thus fixes the perf downside that @Raphael spoke about.

Here is the plugin XML definition (in your `di.xml` file):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory">
        <plugin name="your_plugin_unique_nane" type="Your\Plugin\Namespace\Plugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

And the plugin code:

```
namespace Your\Plugin\Namespace;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as CoreCollectionFactory;

class Plugin
{
    /**
     * @param CoreCollectionFactory $subject
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function afterCreate(CoreCollectionFactory $subject, Collection $collection)
    {
        $collection->addUrlRewrite();

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way, but plugin class is not executing. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Export your products to a csv file

from the csv file in Excel use this formula for the url_key column

> ="https://www.yourdomain.com/"&P103&".html"

where "P103" is the url_key column